# How to increase the height of an svg image in css?

Tags: html, css, svg, viewbox

I am working on **svg image** (as shown in the screenshot marked by an arrow having four triangles) **html code** as show below belonging to the webpage in which I want to **increase the height of it**.

[image]

```
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 30 30">
   <style>.path-one,.path-two{fill-rule:evenodd;clip-rule:evenodd;fill:#00afc9}.path-two{opacity:.4;fill:#93c83d}</style>
   <path class="path-one" d="M30 30H0V0"></path>
   <path class="path-two" d="M0 30V0h30"></path>
</svg>
```

I tried adding inline `width="150px"` and `height="150px"` in svg tag but it doesn't seem to work.

**Problem Statement:**

I am wondering what changes I should make in the code above so that the height of the svg image gets changed

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can achieve the same result using CSS and it will be easier to handle:

```css
.box {
  display:inline-block;
  width:150px;
  height:150px;
  background:
    linear-gradient(to top left   ,transparent 49.3%,rgb(147, 200, 61,0.4) 50%),
    linear-gradient(to bottom left,transparent 49.3%,#00afc9 50%);
}
```

```html
<div class="box">

</div>
```

You can also integrate it as background for your black bar:

```css
.box {
  height:60px;
  background:
    linear-gradient(to top left   ,transparent 49.3%,rgb(147, 200, 61,0.4) 50%),
    linear-gradient(to bottom left,transparent 49.3%,#00afc9 50%),
    #000;
  background-size:60px 100%;
  background-repeat:no-repeat;
}
```

```html
<div class="box">

</div>
```

Comment: I am wondering if you had a look on the [webpage](http://www.cpac.ca/en/episode/) I want to fit that svg image inside the bar. I tried your code but it didn't work. .

Comment: @flash try to add this CSS code and remove the SVG `.breaking-news-slider {background:linear-gradient(to top left   ,transparent 49.3%,rgb(147, 200, 61,0.4) 50%) left/150px 100% no-repeat,
    linear-gradient(to bottom left,transparent 49.3%,#00afc9 50%) left/150px 100% no-repeat,#000}`

Comment: I am bit confused where do you want me to do what.

Comment: @flash you no more need any SVG or anoher element for that shape .. check my last edit to see that I have applied the background to your black bar. So simply add the same CSS to your bar in your code

Comment: When you say remove the svg, where do you want me to remove it

Comment: @flash remove it from your code, no need it any more since I will do the same thing using only background (check my updated answer)

Comment: I have removed the svg, in which html you want me integrated that css.

Comment: @flash the back bar having the class `breaking-news-slider` simply add my last code to that element

Comment: you mean to say this one `class="breaking-news-slider slick-initialized slick-slider" id="js-breaking-news-slider"` ?

Comment: I added there but the height is not increasing in a proper way.

Comment: @flash show me how you added it, there is no more height involved since it's a background. Did you get my last code? there is two snippet in my answer (refresh the page if you only see one)

Comment: I will let you know step-by-step what I did. I will mark your answer because I think it worked.

Comment: This is what I did. Let me know if its ok.

`.breaking-news-slider {
    height: 60px;
    background: linear-gradient(to top left ,transparent 49.3%,rgb(147, 200, 61,0.4) 50%), linear-gradient(to bottom left,transparent 49.3%,#00afc9 50%), #000;
    background-size: 60px 100%;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
}


@media (min-width: 48em) {
.cpac-breaking>.cpac-icon svg {
    display: none !important;
}
}
.cpac-breaking
 {
  background: none !important;
 }`

Comment: I want to give you bounty but it says after 16 hours. I will do that after 16 hours.

Answer (score 2):

apply it on the svg element:

```
svg { width: 150px; height: 150px }
```

Answer (score 0):

Please note that, the svg image is actually taking the height and width that you want to set by using height and width properties only. The problem however lies in you paths. You can add a background-color to svg element to verify that it actually is changing the height and width.

```
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" height="300" width="150" 
viewBox="0 0 30 
30" enable-background="new 0 0 311.7 311.5">
<path fill="red" class="path-one" d="M30 30H0V0"></path>
<path fill="blue" class="path-two" d="M0 30V0h30"></path>
</svg>

 <!-- CSS Code-->
<style>
svg {
  background-color: black;
}
</style>
```

A handly website to quickly play around SVG images is :
https://www.rapidtables.com/web/tools/svg-viewer-editor.html

Make good use of it.

Comment: please note that height and width are intrinsic to SVG tag, they work no matter what.  :)